# Problem with compiling in ShareLaTeX

Tags: errors, compiling, input, sharelatex

I have a problem with compiling a document in ShareLaTeX. I want to compile a tex-data, that is including an input document (name: `config.tex`) that seems to cause the problem. The data that has to be compiled looks basically like this:

```
\input{config.tex}  
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

.......

\end{document}
```

---

ShareLaTeX gives me this error :

```
Emergency stop.
<*> config.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

---

config.tex looks like this:

```
\documentclass[%

%.......


\newcommand{\stack}[2]{\makebox[1cm][c]{$\stackrel{#1}{#2}$}}
```

---

What to change in the `config.tex` or is the problem a different one?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass[%
 paper=a4,
 fontsize=10pt,
 ngerman
 ]{scrartcl}

% Basics für Codierung und Sprache
% ==========================================
\newcommand{\flo}[1]{\Floor*{#1}}
\newcommand{\no}[1]{\Norm*{#1}}
\newcommand{\sk}[1]{\sprod*{#1}}
\newcommand{\enb}[1]{\enbrace*{#1}}
\newcommand{\penb}[1]{\penbrace*{#1}}
\newcommand{\benb}[1]{\benbrace*{#1}}
\newcommand{\stack}[2]{\makebox[1cm][c]{$\stackrel{#1}{#2}$}}

Comment: This is the content of the config.tex : wasnt able to paste everything cause it has to many characters.

Comment: Please edit your post and add it to it, and try to create a [_minimal_ working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: oh your log shows that `config.tex` is the file that you are processing but that is wrong you should be processing teh file that you did not name that starts with `\input{config]`

Answer (score 1):

You have two files, `zzzz.tex` that looks like

```
\input{config.tex}  
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
.......
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

and `config.tex` that looks like

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}%

%.......


\newcommand{\stack}[2]{\makebox[1cm][c]{$\stackrel{#1}{#2}$}}
```

If you process `zzzz.tex` with latex you get:

```
 pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode zzzz
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./zzzz.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.14> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(./config.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty)))
(./zzzz.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdfte
x.map}] (./zzzz.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/am
sfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on zzzz.pdf (1 page, 10187 bytes).
Transcript written on zzzz.log.
```

But if you process `config.tex` you get

```
$ pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode config
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./config.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.14> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty)))
! Emergency stop.
<*> config

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on config.log.
```

which is the error you show. You need to process your document, not the configuration setup file.